# How to Solve these equations by Mathematica and plot the results' curve?

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

I'm working on an Apollo re-entry program(from 160 Km to 60 Km) and would like to solve the equations of the trajectory. I'm using these equations of motion to calculate the trajectory of the spacecraft.

`V̇=-(D/m)-g Sin[θ]`

`OverDot[φ]=-(V Cos[θ]/(r+h))`

`OverDOt[θ]=(L/m V)-(g Cos[θ]/V)`

`ḣ=V Sin[θ]`

Drag and lift are calculated using Newtonian Theory:

`cd=2 Sin[α]^3`

`cl=2 Sin[α]^2 Cos[α]`

`D=(1/2) cd ρ V^2 s`

`L=(1/2) cl ρ V^2 s`

Density and gravity:

`g=g0*(r/r+h)`

`ρ=ρ0*Exp[h0-h/H]`

Constants:

`s=Quantity[12.0687,"Meters"^2];(*surface area of the capsule*)`

`r=Quantity[6371,"Kilometers"];(*radius of the Earth*)`

`g0=Quantity[9.80612,"Meters"*"Seconds"^-2];(*gravity at 160 km*)`

`ρ0=Quantity[1.20654,"Kilograms"*"Meters"^-3];(*density at 160 km*)`

`m=Quantity[5500,"Kilograms"];(*mass of capsule*)`

`h0=Quantity[60,"Kilometers"];(*end of sensible atmosphere*)`

`H=Quantity[7,"Kilometers"];(*scaled height*)`

Inputs:

`V=Quantity[7162.8,"Meters"*"Seconds"^-1]; (*velocity of capsule*)`

`φ=10.556°; (*angular range*)`

`θ=-2.0°; (*flight path angle*)`

`α=53°; (*attack angle*)`

`h=Quantity[160,"Kilometers"]; (*altitude*)`

I am just beginning on working on Mathematica and would like to ask how can I solve these equations and get as a result a curve of `altitude(km) vs time(s)`

Comment: The air density profile is really given by the equation ρ=ρ0*Exp[h0-h/H]? Cause this expression do not reproduce the expected behavior of the atmosphere. Is the attack angle considered constant over the entire reentrance?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can solve the above system of coupled differential equations using `NDSolve` *Mathematica* function numerically.

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\mathrm dV}{\mathrm dt} &= -\frac{D}{m}-g\sin\theta\\
\frac{\mathrm d\theta}{\mathrm dt} &= \frac{1}{V}\left(\frac{L}{m} -g\cos\theta\right)\\
\frac{\mathrm d\varphi}{\mathrm dt} &= -\frac{V\cos\theta}{r+h}\\
\frac{\mathrm dh}{\mathrm dt} &= V\sin\theta
\end{align}
$$

First one needs to assign correctly the equations, initial values and its variables. The expressions for g and $\rho$ are incorrect and have to be modified. A little care must to be taken in respect to different units used (km,m). The drag force D symbol cannot be used because MMA will recognize this as the derivative function. Here I changed it to Fd. Trigonometric functions entries must be in radians instead degrees and need to be changed with `N[angle Degrees]`. So we have

```
s = 12.0687;                       (*surface area of the capsule m^2*)
r = 6371000;                       (*radius of the Earth m *)
g0 = 9.80612;                      (*gravity at surface m/s^2 *)
\[Rho]0 = 1.20654;                 (*density at surface kg/m^3 *)
m = 5500;                          (*mass of capsule kg *)
h0 = 60000;                        (*end of sensible atmosphere m *)
H = 7000;                          (*scaled height m *)

V0 = 7162.8;                       (*velocity of capsule  m/s*)
h0 = 160000;                       (*altitude m *)
\[CurlyPhi]0 = N[10.556 Degree];   (*angular range*)
\[Theta]0 = N[-2.0 Degree];        (*flight path angle*)
\[Alpha] =  N[53 Degree];          (*attack angle*)   

g[z_] := g0*(r^2/(r + z)^2);
\[Rho][z_] := \[Rho]0*Exp[-z/H];

cd = 2 (Sin[\[Alpha]])^3;
cl = 2 (Sin[\[Alpha]])^2 Cos[\[Alpha]];

Fd[v_, z_, t_] := (1/2) cd \[Rho][z] v^2 s;
L[v_, z_, t_] := (1/2) cl \[Rho][z] v^2 s;

sol = NDSolve[{
    V'[t] == -(Fd[V[t], h[t], t]/m) - g[h[t]] Sin[\[Theta][t]],
    \[Theta]'[t] == L[V[t], h[t], t]/(m V[t]) - g[h[t]] Cos[\[Theta][t]]/V[t],
    \[CurlyPhi]'[t] == -(V[t] Cos[\[Theta][t]]/(r + h[t])),
    h'[t] == V[t] Sin[\[Theta][t]],
    h[0] == h0,
    V[0] == V0,
    \[Theta][0] == \[Theta]0,
    \[CurlyPhi][0] == \[CurlyPhi]0
    }, {V, \[Theta], \[CurlyPhi], h}, {t, 0, 800}];

pl1 = Plot[Evaluate[V[t] /. sol], {t, 0, 800}, PlotRange -> All, 
   FrameLabel -> {StyleForm["t (s)", FontSize -> 13], 
     StyleForm["v (km/s)", FontSize -> 13]},
   Frame -> True, PlotStyle -> {Directive[Red, Thick]}, 
   ImageSize -> 300];
pl2 = Plot[Evaluate[(180*\[Theta][t]/\[Pi]) /. sol], {t, 0, 800}, 
   PlotRange -> All, 
   FrameLabel -> {StyleForm["t (s)", FontSize -> 13], 
     StyleForm["\[Theta] (degrees)", FontSize -> 13]},
   Frame -> True, PlotStyle -> {Directive[Green, Thick]}, 
   ImageSize -> 300];
pl3 = Plot[Evaluate[(180*\[CurlyPhi][t]/\[Pi]) /. sol], {t, 0, 800}, 
   PlotRange -> All, 
   FrameLabel -> {StyleForm["t (s)", FontSize -> 13], 
     StyleForm["\[CurlyPhi] (degrees)", FontSize -> 13]},
   Frame -> True, PlotStyle -> {Directive[Orange, Thick]}, 
   ImageSize -> 300];
pl4 = Plot[Evaluate[(h[t]/1000) /. sol], {t, 0, 800}, 
   PlotRange -> All, 
   FrameLabel -> {StyleForm["t (s)", FontSize -> 13], 
     StyleForm["h (km)", FontSize -> 13]},
   Frame -> True, PlotStyle -> {Directive[Blue, Thick]}, 
   ImageSize -> 300];
GraphicsGrid[{{pl1, pl2}, {pl3, pl4}}]


ApoloPath = 
  Table[{\[CurlyPhi][t], ((r + h[t])/1000)}, {t, 0, 800}] /. sol;
pl5 = ListPolarPlot[ApoloPath, PlotStyle -> Red, 
   PolarAxes -> Automatic, 
   PolarGridLines -> {{0, Pi/2, Pi, 3 Pi/2}, {0.2*r/1000, 0.4*r/1000, 
      0.6*r/1000, 0.8*r/1000}}, 
   PolarTicks -> {"Degrees", Automatic}];
pl6 = Graphics[{Hue[0.6, 0.3, 0.7, .7], 
    Disk[{0, 0}, r/1000, {-0.3, 0.3}]}];
Show[pl5, pl6, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, r/1000}, {-7000 Sin[0.3], 7000 Sin[0.3]}}]
ApoloPathTime = 


Table[{r (\[CurlyPhi][t] + 0.15336)/
       1852., (h[t]/(1000*0.3048))}, {t, 0, 800}] /. sol;

TimeTicks = 
  Table[{r (\[CurlyPhi][t] + 0.15336)/
       1852., (h[t]/(1000*0.3048))}, {t, 0, 800, 30}] /. sol;

pl7 = ListLinePlot[ApoloPathTime, 
   ScalingFunctions -> {"Reverse", Identity}, PlotRange -> All, 
   FrameLabel -> {StyleForm["Range (Nautical Miles)", FontSize -> 13],
      StyleForm["h (1000 ft)", FontSize -> 13]}, Frame -> True, 
   PlotStyle -> {Directive[Black, Thick]}, ImageSize -> 300];

pl8 = ListPlot[TimeTicks, ScalingFunctions -> {"Reverse", Identity}, 
   PlotMarkers -> {"|"}, PlotRange -> All, 
   FrameLabel -> {StyleForm["Range (Nautical Miles)", FontSize -> 13],
      StyleForm["h (1000 ft)", FontSize -> 13]}, Frame -> True, 
   PlotStyle -> {Directive[Red, Thick]}, ImageSize -> 300];

Show[pl7, pl8]
```

In this manner the output functions will be
[image]

The above behavior shows us that the landing must occur in a time around 800 seconds.
Also, one can plot the the trajectory of the Apollo spacecraft parametrically ($\varphi(t)$,$r+h(t)$) in polar coordinates adjusting correctly the units to meters and degrees.

[image]

[image]

These results can be compared with the next plot

[image]

Comment: very helpful answer!